# Jquery .each, but only that current element

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using the following script

```
$('.cat_glass_thumbs ul li').each(function(){
    $(this).click(function(){
        orig_src = $(this).attr('data-orig');
        $('.cat_glass_thumbs a img').attr('src', orig_src);
    });
});
```

I have loop that outputs multiple divs, all of them the same structure, different content.

Right my jquery works ".cat_glass_thumbs" div, if I flick on the li, it will update the src in every .cat_glass_thumb, instead of just updating the one I am in.

Tips/pointers would be appreciated

html of each for reference:

```
<div class="cat_glass_thumbs">

      <a href="" title="Black/Silver" class="product-image thumbnail">
          <span class="main_image">
               <img src="t/2064-a-blk-slv-52-angle.jpg" alt="Black/Silver">
          </span>
      </a>


       <ul id="thumbs_container">
            <li class="img_thumbs" data-orig="/t/-2064-a-blk-slv-52-angle.jpg">
            </li>
            <li class="img_thumbs" data-orig="/t/-2064-a-blk-slv-52-front.jpg">
            </li>
             <li class="img_thumbs" data-orig="/t/-2064-b-blk-gld-52-angle.jpg">
             </li>
        </ul>

     </div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Drop the `each`, it's useless in this case (jQuery automatically does it for you):

```
$('.cat_glass_thumbs ul li').click(function(){
    var orig_src = $(this).data('orig');
    $('a img', this).attr('src', orig_src);
});
```

### JS Fiddle Demo

Note that I used `$('a img', this)` in the form of `$( selector [, context ] )` described in the [jQuery documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jquery/).

---

**Edit**

Your JS code alone made me think of another HTML structure. To fit the one you posted, you need to target the image in the parent `.cat_glass_thumbs` using [`$.closest()`](http://api.jquery.com/closest/):

```
$('.cat_glass_thumbs ul li').click(function(){ 
    var orig_src = $(this).data('orig');
    $('a img', $(this).closest('.cat_glass_thumbs')).attr('src', orig_src);
});
```

### Updated JS Fiddle

> [**$.closest()**](http://api.jquery.com/closest/)
>
> **Description:** For each element in the set, get the first element that matches the selector by testing the element itself and traversing up through its **ancestors** in the DOM tree.

Comment: I went ahead an added html for reference as to how each container looks

Comment: @RMH Always post your HTML (a reduced test case at least) to get the right answer ;) I updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

I think this will work:

```
$('.cat_glass_thumbs ul li').each(function(){
    $(this).click(function(){
        orig_src = $(this).attr('data-orig');
        $(this).find("a img").attr('src', orig_src);
    });
});
```

Comment: I went ahead an added html for reference as to how each container looks

Answer (score 0):

$(this) element in your example points to all '.cat_glass_thumbs ul li', 
you must pass variable to $.each

```
$('.cat_glass_thumbs ul li').each(function($currentElement){
    $currentElement.click(function(){
        orig_src = $(this).attr('data-orig');
        $(this).children("img").attr('src', orig_src);
    });
});
```

Comment: I went ahead an added html for reference as to how each container looks

Comment: Do you have any click event on .thumbs_container or .cat_glass_thumbs ?